# How do I resolve an error in my yaml file?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to install docker on a node using an ansible playbook, but I keep getting an error. Here's the playbook

```
---
- host: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
  - name Add Docker GPG key
    apt_key: url=https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg

  - name: Add Docker APT repository
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb [arch=and64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu {{ansible_distributionrelease}} stable

  - name: Install list of packages
    apt:
      name: "{{item}}"
      state: installed
      update_cache: yes
    with_items:
      - apt-transport-https
      - ca-certificates
      - curl
      - software-properties-common
      - docker-ce
```

And here's the error message

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/home/ubuntu/docker.yml': line 7, column 12, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  - name Add Docker GPG key
    apt_key: url=https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
           ^ here
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake. I was missing a colon on this line after 'name'

```
- name: Add Docker GPG key
```